Draw a filled polygon with fill color *inside* the outline
I want to draw a polygon as an outline and fill it with a specific color. This should be an easy enough task for PIL... Unfortunately the fill argument produces an image that bleeds out of the outline... Demonstration:
Step 1, lets show clearly what my outline should look like:
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

vertices = [(44, 124),
            (50, 48),
            (74, 46),
            (73, 123),
            (44, 124)]
                  
# draw as an outline
image = Image.new('RGB', (150, 150), 'black')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw.line(vertices, fill='blue', width=1)
image.save(r'outline.png')

This produces the image below:

This is great, and i can confirm in Photoshop that my corners corresponds to the specified coordinates. Now step 2, lets do the same using the polygon function and draw a filled polygon:
# draw as a filled polygon
image = Image.new('RGB', (150, 150), 'black')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw.polygon(vertices, fill='white', outline='blue', width=1)
image.save(r'filled.png')

Notice the two pixels appearing on this shape? These white pixels are at (75, 46) and (43, 124) which are outside the boundary.

This is not acceptable. The filled polygon should not rasterize beyond its outline. Here is the desired output I would have expected (mocked up in Photoshop):

QUESTION
At the end of the day, I want to write a function which will take n vertices to draw a clean polygon with a filled boundary the does not exceed the outline. Also, for technical reasons I cannot use matplotlib, which means I cannot use skimage.draw.polygon_perimeter because it needs matplotlib. Any other package (especially if leveraging numpy) would be best.

Here's my current solution: use scipy.ndimage.binary_fill_holes to fill the hole.
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

vertices = [(44, 124),
            (50, 48),
            (74, 46),
            (73, 123),
            (44, 124)]
            
# draw the outline as a bitmap
outline = Image.new('1', (150, 150))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(outline)
draw.line(vertices, fill=1, width=1)
outline = np.array(outline)

# fill with ndimage.binary_fill_holes
fill = ndimage.binary_fill_holes(outline)

# remove outline from fill using a logical "and"
fill = fill & ~outline

# create the final image
canvas = np.zeros((150,150,3), dtype=np.uint8)
canvas[fill == True] = [255, 255, 255] # fill with white
canvas[outline == True] = [0, 0, 255] # outline is blue

final = Image.fromarray(canvas)
final.save('final.png')

Result:

This works for now, but I need to compare with ImageDraw for speed as i need to run this millions of times.

The clear answer for speed: opencv-python
import numpy as np
import cv2

# create a black canvas
image = np.zeros((150,150,3), np.uint8)

vertices = np.array([(44, 124),
                     (50, 48),
                     (74, 46),
                     (73, 123),
                     (44, 124)], np.int32)
vertices = vertices.reshape((-1,1,2))

# fill the polygon with white
cv2.fillPoly(image, [vertices], (255, 255, 255)) 

# draw the blue outline (opencv uses BGR instead of RGB)
cv2.polylines(image, [vertices], True, (255,0,0), 1)

cv2.imwrite("opencv.png", image)


